# How to fix Blazor Web App error: The name 'rendermode' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I am working with Blazor Web App in .NET 8 using Visual Studio 2022. while creating Blazor Web App having boilerplate code, i am getting "The name 'rendermode' does not exist in the current context" any suggestion or advise?

[image]

My Project File looks:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you share the Counter.razor code?